# Class Names are Returned but get_class_methods returns Null using spl_autoload_register

Tags: php

I am trying to read some class files stored in a folder and get their methods.

However, the `get_class_methods` is returning null. But if I put my `server_defines` file and `index.php` into the `v1` folder, everything works as it should.

I'm unsure what is going on, since it appears to me (a novice) that everything is included.

**Here is the folder structure**

- Api

  - server_defines.php
  - Test

    - index.php
  - v1

    - MyMasterClass.php
    - Operations

      - OneClass.php
      - TwoClass.php
      - ThreeClass.php

### server_defines.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT ^ E_DEPRECATED);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt');
if (!defined("SERVER_DOCUMENT_ROOT")) {
        define("SERVER_DOCUMENT_ROOT", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/");
}
define( "SERVER_API_PATH", SERVER_DOCUMENT_ROOT . "v1/" );
define( "SERVER_API_OPERATIONS_PATH", SERVER_API_PATH . "Operations/" );
```

### Test/index.php

```
require_once( $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ] . "/server_defines.php" );

spl_autoload_register( function ( $class ) {
    $sFile = SERVER_API_PATH . str_replace( '\\', '/', $class ) . '.php';
    if (file_exists( $sFile )) {
        echo "requiring file: " . $sFile . "<br/>";
        require $sFile;
    }
} );

var_dump(MyMasterClass::getClassesAndMethods());
```

*** Which Outputs***

```
requiring file: /Users/myname/Documents/GitHub/myproject/Api/v1/MyMasterClass.php


folder_contents: array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(80) "/Users/myname/Documents/GitHub/myproject/Api/v1/Operations/OneClass.php"
  [1]=>
  string(75) "/Users/myname/Documents/GitHub/myproject/Api/v1/Operations/TwoClass.php"
  [2]=>
  string(75) "/Users/myname/Documents/GitHub/myproject/Api/v1/Operations/ThreeClass.php"
}


basename: OneClass
get_class_methods: NULL


basename: TwoClass
get_class_methods: NULL


basename: ThreeClass
get_class_methods: NULL
```

### MyMasterClass.php

```
class MyMasterClass {

        public function __toString () {
            return $this->result;
        }

        public function __construct (  ) {

        }

        public static function getClassesAndMethods () {
            $api = new API();
            return $api->buildClassesAndMethods();
        }


        private function buildClassesAndMethods () {
            $folder_contents = glob( SERVER_API_OPERATIONS_PATH . '*.{php}', GLOB_BRACE );

            echo "<br/>folder_contents: ";
            var_dump( $folder_contents );
            echo "<br/>";

            $collection = array();
            foreach ($folder_contents as $name) {

                $name = basename( $name, ".php" );

                echo "<br/>basename: " . $name . "<br/>";
                echo "<br/>get_class_methods: ";
                var_dump( get_class_methods( $name ) );
                echo "<br/>";

            }
            return $collection;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why not use reflection? https://3v4l.org/XgJg9

Comment: I assume get_class_methods won't try to load your class. Try calling `class_exists` with the second argumetn `true` beforehand.

Comment: @ChristianM I added `var_dump( class_exists( $name ) ) ` to the foreach just after the basename method. They all return `bool(false)`. I don't understand. It just listed all the classes.

Comment: I wrote with second argument true. You want to trigger the autoload

Answer (score 0):

When you move your classes to subfolder, you autoloader isn't able to load those classes since it covers only files located in `SERVER_API_PATH`. Try to update your autoload method or load classes manually using `require_once`.

Try

```
...
        foreach ($folder_contents as $name) {

            require_once($name);
            $name = basename( $name, ".php" );

            echo "<br/>basename: " . $name . "<br/>";
            echo "<br/>get_class_methods: ";
            var_dump( get_class_methods( $name ) );
            echo "<br/>";

        }
...
```